# Software to rearrange a set of spatial connections

Tags: windows

I am not naming the field on purpose. I have consulted with others and have done my own research to know that there is currently no tool known in my field. I am suspecting that this task is not incredibly complicated, and probably a tool that can easily do this already exists, just in a completely different field, completely unknown to me. I just need some people with more diverse knowledge of what already exists to give me a hint.

As such, I am inviting you to see what needs to be accomplished, and possibly suggest to me what software can possibly be used to do this.

I am working on a series of tasks involving analysis and rearrangement of a collection of objects connected to each other in certain ways. I may need to be able to rearrange these spatial diagrams to make sense or to propose an arrangement that better satisfies other logistical conditions.

--

I usually start with a collection of nodes. In the sample diagram, I have 4 nodes (1,2,3 and 4). Each node may have a various number of available "connections", where it can be connected to other nodes. This number can vary, and I hope I will be able to create nodes with custom number of connections.

[image: simplified diagram]

My starting data lists what connections do exists, and I can easily diagram them, say on a chart like this. Once the lines presenting connections are created, I have a complete system, like the one on the left side. Of course, there are many more nodes than 4 and they all have various number of relations to each other.

Then, I need to rearrange the nodes, either by dragging them manually, or automatically, maybe I will be able to use some sort of scripting interface that comes with the tool. The rearrangement always consists of the same thing: moving the nodes around until the lines connecting them are less of a mess and / or make more sense when transposed against other maps such as logistics routes, etc.

What is necessary and currently missing from any graphic software I have attempted to use so far, is the ability to create the network that once completed, can then be rearranged while keeping the connections intact, meaning connected. I want to be able to re-route as needed, single them out or bunch them up, pull one or more connections to the side for an alternate routing, take a few and route them around a corner, this always differ according to the project requirements, but they MUST STAY CONNECTED. Sort of as if this was an actual physical mesh, I should be able to tangle or untangle it in various ways (around something, through narrows, along a route, diverse routes, etc, etc) never losing the initial way they were all connected, because how they are connected is essential. Routing is only an optimization.

I accept that such a tool may not yet exist. I am willing to use a method that exists in other software, that would allow me to adapt it to my purpose.

This doesn't need to be database connected tool, I would be perfectly fine with rearranging it to the condition I need and just using that as a graphic map of a solution. I can then think further about how to connect / translate / script that solution further into a data process.

I just can't find a tool to allow this unbreakable rubber band manipulation so to speak.